# why is there only 1 datepicker visible?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have created a bootstrap datepicker:

```
app.directive('datePicker', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'datepicker.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      console.log('it works');
      $scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
      };
      $scope.today();

      $scope.showWeeks = true;
      $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
        $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
      };

      $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.dt = null;
      };

      // Disable weekend selection
      $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
        return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
      };

      $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
      };
      $scope.toggleMin();

      $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
      };

      $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yy'",
        'starting-day': 1
      };

      $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'shortDate'];
      $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

      console.log('end of controller');
    }
  };
});
```

When I place 2 of these directives on my page I only see 1 of them? Why is that?
How can I get 2 independent ones so I select 1 date in the first picker and another in the second one?

plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/QoiLt339m9x6pAswY0Kc?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becouse you miss `restrict:'E'` property inside directive body.
To make them independent add `scope:{}` property it makes scope isolated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aXW0zFR4t9kj75HxZ3kd?p=preview

Comment: why is the selection of data disabled?

Comment: i guess something wrong with `max="'2015-06-22'"` param in datepicker.html